# SQL Server compare values of two rows of same table and get not matching column names

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I need to compare two rows (`INSERTED` & `DELETED`) of the same table and compare values. And then I need to get the not matching columns. Inside a trigger.

Here what I've tried so far but I 've no idea of how to compare these two rows and get column names which contains different values .

```
SELECT * 
FROM inserted i
INNER JOIN deleted d ON d.PurchasingDocItemNo = i.PurchasingDocItemNo 
                     AND d.PurchasingDocNo = i.PurchasingDocNo
                     AND d.ReferenceDocumentNo = i.ReferenceDocumentNo
                     AND d.ProductNo = i.ProductNo
```

Comment: you can add WHERE condition all over other fields potentially different or use Sql Server CdC or change tracking

Comment: So, you are looking for a way to get the names of the columns that the update statement changed? read about [`columns_updated`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186329.aspx). examples [here](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/1479821/Using-ColumnsUpdated-in-a-Trigger.htm) and [there](http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/piotr_rodak/archive/2010/04/28/columns-updated.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your select to :

```
SELECT
-- For each column you're checking.  Also account for ISNull if you need to
CASE WHEN I.Col1 = D.Col1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS Col1Changed.......
FROM INSERTED I
INNER JOIN DELETED D on (I.<PK> = D.<PK>)
```